# Codeigniter - cache - server?

Tags: codeigniter, caching

After a couple of years with no cache problems in Codeigniter, I discovered one. I have see the problem described other places, but with no solution that works for me.

If I for example change some plain html text in a view and upload a new file and press <kbd>F5</kbd> the old cached file is shown. If I afterwards press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> the new is shown, and <kbd>F5</kbd> again gives me back the old cached file. I have tried to flush the browser cache manually, but we no effect.  After a couple of minutes the old cached file gets replaced with the new one. This issue gives me problems with login and logout.

I have without luck placed the following code in both the login and logout controller;

```
$this->output->cache(0);            
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

I have not activated output cache in any controller `($this->output->cache(n))` or have a cache folder (application/cache or system/cache/(beore 2.0.0)) or use db cache `(['cache_on'] = FALSE)` in the config file.

I am using:
Codeigniter 2.0.0
Firefox 21.0

I think that the cache files are stored somewhere on the Linux server, but where and how to flush, I don't know.

Any help or pointing in the right direction will be fine. Thx!

Best regards
Martin

Comment: Did you check the HTML to see if they were being set properly, and the dates were correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I don´t know. Hove do I check the HTML file for correct days? IS it the last modified date - and Thanks again.

Comment: If you use Firefox, you could use the Firebug addon to check the HTML source of the page. (right-click inspect)

Comment: Thanks. I have Firebug and done inspecting. Where and what do I have to look after? - everything in the HTML file looks fine to me.

Comment: Click on the network tab in firebug. Refresh the page, then select your page from the list (usually the very top item) and click on the headers tab on the right. There you can see exactly what cache headers are being served for your page.

Comment: @Jeemusu. Perfect - the network tab is the opening of a brand new world for me. Many thanks for your help. By inspecting and reading question no.: 11745368I, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cache files are not deleted before they expire. Cache files are saved in `application/cache` folder. you can manually delete it from there.

Additionally, you can better manage your cache(programatically), by either adding [cache helper](https://github.com/stevenbenner/codeigniter-cache-helper) or extending your output class with [clear page cache](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Clear-Page-Cache)

Comment: In my Config file I have set:

$config['cache_path'] = '';

And I do not have nither a application/cache or system/cache folder.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. 
So I can't delete them, because the folder is not there. As far as I know, the cache helper and extending of the output class with clear page cache will look into the folder, that I don't have. Or am I wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes. it would try to delete the file from there. It's odd that you don't have cache folder. Take a look at your `config` file to see if your `$config['cache_path']` has been changed.

Comment: Thanks. The Config['cache_path'] has not been changed, it is left blank, default pointing to application/cache.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the question by inspecting af following question no. 11745368I.